# How do I evaluate $\int x^t e^{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: integration

I have an integral that looks like:
$$\int x^t e^{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}t$$
Is there a way to evaluate an integral of this form?  Will this involve the Gamma function?

Comment: Are you sure that is what you mean? $e^{x^3}$ is constant with respect to $t$, so you can pull it out.

Comment: Assuming you mean $dx$ and not $dt$, this antiderivative will indeed have an incomplete gamma function in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int x^t e^{x^3}dt=e^{x^3}\int x^t dt=e^{x^3}\frac{x^t}{\ln(x)}+ c.$$